# How to match all words but "stop" in a string by regex

Tags: php, regex, string

another regex question. I use PHP, and have a string: `fdjkaljfdlstopfjdslafdj`. You see there is a `stop` in the middle. I just want to replace any other words excluding that `stop`.  i try to use `[^stop]`, but it also includes the `s` at the end of the string.

## My Solution

Thanks everyone’s help here.

I also figure out a solution with pure RegEx method(I mean in my knowledge scoop to RegEx.  PCRE verbs are too advanced for me).  But it needs 2 steps.  I don’t want to mix PHP method in, because sometimes the jobs are out of coding area, i.e. multi-renaming filenames in Total Commander.

Let’s see the string: `xxxfooeoropwfoo,skfhlk;afoofsjre,jhgfs,vnhufoolsjunegpq`.  For example, I want to keep all `foo`s in this string, and replace any other `non-foo` greedily into `---`.

First, I need to find all the non-foo between each `foo`: `(?<=foo).+?(?=foo)`.
The string will turn into `xxxfoo---foo---foo---foolsjunegpq`, just both sides `non-foo` words left now.

Then use `[^-]+(?=foo)|(?<=foo)[^-]+`.
This time: `---foo---foo---foo---foo---`. All words but `foo` have been turned into `---`.

Comment: Replace by what? Also what if `stop` is there multiple times?

Comment: actually, i just dont want to include "stop".  its like to reverse the method /stop/, choosing anything else but "stop" whenever it appears.

Answer (score 1):

> i just dont want to include "stop"...

You can skip it by using [PCRE verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) `(*SKIP)(*F)` try like this

```
stop(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vQ4lO0/1)

or sequence: [(stop)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!(?1)).)+](https://regex101.com/r/cE3yV9/1)

or for  words: [stop(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+](https://regex101.com/r/eU7gM1/1)

Comment: Thanks.  But I am a beginner in RegEx.  So PCRE verbs seems too complicated for me now.  And I use RegEx Tester(v3.2.0.0) to test the result.  Error will occur when those PCRE verbs appear...

Comment: @JerryZhang Welcome! Try [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vQ4lO0/1) for testing. There's explanation on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

`[^stop]` doesn't means any text that is NOT `stop`. It just means any character that is not one of the 4 characters inside `[...]` which is in this case `s,t,o,p`.

Better to split on the text you don't want to match:

```
$s = 'fdjkaljfdlstopfjdslafdjstopfoobar';

php> $arr = preg_split('/stop/', $s);

php> print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => fdjkaljfdl
    [1] => fjdslafdj
    [2] => foobar
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  But actually, I wonder is there a way just using one regex that can do the same work.  I am studying on regex now, so I prefer regex to any other method.  I can use `stop` in regex to represent any `stop` in a string, so I think there should be a regex way to do the opposite work, like `!stop` in PHP.

Comment: `preg_split` is using a single regex `/stop/` only. Btw if you show the code you already have then may be I can suggest something different.

Comment: Thanks anubhava.  It is just an excercise.  No other codes.  I just thought regex could do any string work without other method helps.  But it seems sometimes I don't have to stick to one point.

Comment: Actually first argument in `preg_split` is indeed a regex i.e. `/stop/` and it is much simpler to use split rather than a complicated regex

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize this to any pattern:

```
(?<neg>stop)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?s:.)+?(?=\Z|(?&neg))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU5oJ7/1)

Just put the pattern you don't want in the `neg` group.

This regex will try to do the following for any character position:

- Match the pattern you don't want. If it matches, discard it with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and restart another match at this position.
- If the pattern you don't want doesn't match at a particular position, then match anything, until either:

  - You reach the end of the input string (`\Z`)
  - Or the pattern you don't want immediately follows the current matching position (`(?&neg)`)

---

This approach is slower than manually tuning the expression, you could get better performance at the cost of repeating yourself, which avoids the recursion:

```
stop(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?s:.)+?(?=\Z|stop)
```

---

**But** of course, the best approach would be to use the features provided by your language: match the string you *don't* want, then use code to discard it and keep everything else.

In PHP, you can use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to tell the `preg_match_all` function to provide you the offsets of each match.

Comment: Thanks!  But this method is out of my grasp now...  And i can't test it in RegEx Tester(v3.2.0.0). : (  Anyway, I can find some walkaround with PHP to get the result i desire.

Comment: @JerryZhang [here you go](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=93829) - you need to select PCRE in regex tester, but I'd use regex101 instead - it's much better.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me try regex101.